# Rainbowish phenomenon outside my home

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, visible-light, atmospheric-science

I took a photo of an amazing sight I had never seen outside my home ( southern india ) but I could not tell if it was a rainbow type thing or an aurora borealis. Can someone tell what this is and it’s reason of occurrence [image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because in its current form it's not about physics. A version of it might be on topic at [earthscience.se], or perhaps it could be modified into a slightly different question that would be on topic here.

Answer (score 2):

That is due to ice particles high in the atmosphere.  It's a "rainbow type thing", but different from a rainbow caused by water droplets.   The angle between the sun and the rainbow is different from a droplet rainbow.  Also, the ice crystals tend to be oriented with one axis parallel or normal to the ground while suspended in the air,  so the shape of the rainbow is not necessarily an arc like the standard rainbow.  See https://www.crystalinks.com/sundogs.html.

Comment: It looks more like an [iridescent cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iridescent_clouds) than a sundog.